# Match node based on preceding node name and all following nodes of same name as the matched node

Tags: xml, xpath, match, edi

My problem lies in transforming an EDI file, which has been converted to XML, into groups. It contains a dynamic list of messages, so more UNH tags with following BGM tags and DTM tags. I am not looking for XSLT Stylesheet answers.
In this case, I can have between 1 and 35 DTM tags, ALWAYS following the BGM tag.
There are more DTM tags following other tags, like PTY, but I only want to match any DTM tag following a BGM tag and all next sibling DTM tags.

My final goal is to go through all the segments and add them to groups, like described in http://www.truugo.com/edifact/d96a/orders/, where the UNH-FTX would go into GRP0, the following RFF(mandatory)-DTM(Conditional) into GRP1 and so on.
I wish to do this in as few steps as possible in XPATH 1.0.
Thank you in advance!

Illustrative example, where bold = matched nodes. Node count can be up to 35 in a row in this case. In other cases I may have to match up to 200000
<UNH>
  <group>
    <value>1</value>
  </group>
</UNH>
<BGM>
  ...
<BGM>
**<DTM>
  ...
</DTM>

<DTM>
  ...
</DTM>**
<PAI>
  ...
</PAI>
<DTM>
  ...
</DTM>
<PTY>
 ...
</PTY>
...
<UNH>
...
</UNH>
<BGM>
  ...
<BGM>
**<DTM>
  ...
</DTM>

<DTM>
  ...
</DTM>

<DTM>
  ...
</DTM>

<DTM>
  ...
</DTM>**
<IMD>
  ...
</IMD>
<DTM>
  ...
</DTM>
<DTM>
  ...
</DTM>
<PTY>
 ...
</PTY>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is really counter-intuitive to do, but here's how to address sets by filtering with sibling operators:

The first set of DTM immediately after the first BGM

```
//DTM [ (preceding-sibling::*)[name()!="DTM"][last()]  
         = //BGM[1]                                     ]
```

The two DTM following IMD on the second BGM set :

```
//DTM [  (preceding-sibling::*)[name()!="DTM"][last()] 
         = //BGM[2]/following-sibling::IMD[1]           ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works and I actually believe that I understand your solution and I will be able to replicate it further :)